# Is there a way to improve performance when displaying thousends of labels on mapbox view?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Simply it looks like this:

[image]

There is displayed more than 2k labels. When I load that controller it takes more than 10 seconds to finish displaying. Why? **How can I speed it up?**

And this is what I do to display them on the **mapbox**:

```
private func setupMapBox() {

    let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/kunass2/cjcubgbvq1uuq2smt3nup7nzf")
    mapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: url)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapContainerView.addSubview(mapView)

    mapView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
}

private func setupFetchedResultsController() {

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Label>(entityName: "Label")
    let nameDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "text", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "territory.identifier = %@", territory.identifier)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [nameDescriptor]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    reloadAnnotations()
}

private func reloadAnnotations() {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations ?? [])
    mapView.addAnnotations(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!)
}
```

and here are my delegates:

```
//MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    if let label = anObject as? Label {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            mapView.addAnnotation(label)
        case .delete:
            mapView.removeAnnotation(label)
        case .update:
            fallthrough
        case .move:
            mapView.removeAnnotation(label)
            mapView.addAnnotation(label)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - MGLMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
    setupFetchedResultsController()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {

    guard let label = annotation as? Label else {
        return nil
    }
    return LabelAnnotationView(label: label)
}
```

in `viewDidLoad` I simply call:

```
setupMapBox()
```

Comment: You can use Xcode `profile instruments` to find out code hotpot and optimizes it.

Comment: You should cluster your annotations. No one will be able to read all labels zoomed out anyways. Once the user zooms in, the clusters will split and the labels will show.

Comment: @Hannes do you think that this is the point why the app lags?

Comment: Yes definitely! Rendering & displaying that many labels/views it too much. Clustering will solve that problem and also makes it look nicer / better UX.

Comment: Ok, I will do it later and let you know how it works;) Thank you @Hannes

Comment: @Hannes one more quetsion. When my view is in very zoomed in are other  labels being also loaded? Is there a way to deallocate them if they are not in current window of map? and load smoothly when they appear while dragging?

Comment: That should be handled automatically by MapBox (or any other Maps sdk). UIViews out of screen won't be rendered and therefore won't slow down the app.

Comment: I have implemented Cluster but don't know how I can change the image for each annotation based on its GeoJSON name.  
Is anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [MGLSymbolStyleLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.4/Classes/MGLSymbolStyleLayer.html) should be more performant. [This example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/) includes a symbol layer that uses text. Because symbol layers are rendered directly in GL, they are more lightweight.

Annotations use native UIViews, and therefore are less performant when you use many. For more information about the pros and cons of different methods of adding points to a map, see [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/adding-points-to-a-map.html).

Comment: Happy to help out. Could you tell me what format your data is in?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer;) I did it and it works perfect.